# Subset data.frame based on threshold number of value combinations

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to remove rows from my data.frame which don't have their unique combination of values repeated >= 4 times in the data frame. In this example, I only want rows 1,2,6 and 7 because the values IR, IR_OSR, 2 & hello are repeated 4 times within this example.

```
> DB[1:5,c("MegaSite","General.location","ID","call.type")]
  MegaSite General.location ID call.type
1       IR           IR_OSR  2     hello
2       IR           IR_OSR  2     hello
3       IR           IR_OSR  M         x
4       IR           IR_OSR  M         x
5       IR           IR_OSR  M         z
6       IR           IR_OSR  2     hello
7       IR           IR_OSR  2     hello
        > dim(DB)
[1] 25434    76
```

I have tried the following code suggested in another recent question ([Finding value pairs that occur more than once in a data.table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598879/finding-value-pairs-that-occur-more-than-once-in-a-data-table-in-r)),

```
>DB[,.N>3 , list("MegaSite","General.location","ID","call.type")]
```

however I get this error

```
Error in drop && !has.j : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

Here's a link to a larger example data set which has only the relevant columns from my actual dataset:
[DB_IRsample.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pi3uxsxwz4hqm25/DB_IRsample.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
> require(plyr)
> result <- ddply(r,.(MegaSite,General.location,ID,call.type),nrow)
> result <- result[result$V1 >= 4, ]
> result
  MegaSite General.location ID call.type V1
1       IR           IR_OSR  2     hello  4
```

Then you can merge the original data against this `result` to filter out the rows which did not occur at least 4 times:

```
> merge(r, result, all.y=TRUE, by=c("MegaSite", "General.location", "ID", "call.type"))
  MegaSite General.location ID call.type V1
1       IR           IR_OSR  2     hello  4
2       IR           IR_OSR  2     hello  4
3       IR           IR_OSR  2     hello  4
4       IR           IR_OSR  2     hello  4
```

Comment: Thanks this works!
Though I should note that I needed to apply the merge to a new object, e.g. DB2<-merge(....